# Getting albums from Facebook using ionic-native/facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using the `ionic-native/facebook` plugin to get the albums for users who have authorised my app.

After a user has clicked the "log in with facebook" link in the app they are taken to Facebook, they approve the app and then get sent back. At this point I make an API call to get their albums:

```
this.fb.api('/me/?fields=id,name,albums{name,picture,cover_photo{images}}', this.fbPermisions)
.then((res: any) => {
  console.log(res);
})
.catch(this.handleError);
```

This returns an error in the console: `Error processing action - "There was an error making the graph call"`

If however I try either of the following calls then they successfully execute.

```
this.fb.api('/me', this.fbPermisions)
.then((res: any) => {
  console.log(res);
})
.catch(this.handleError);
```

Or

```
this.fb.api('/me/?fields=id,name,albums', this.fbPermisions)
.then((res: any) => {
  console.log(res);
})
.catch(this.handleError);
```

All three calls work absolutely fine if I use the Graph API Explorer.

So, does anybody know why `/me/?fields=id,name,albums{name,picture,cover_photo{images}}` fails within `ionic-native/facebook` but works via the Graph API Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like urlencoding the request gives me what I need.

So instead of:

```
this.fb.api('/me/?fields=id,name,albums{name,picture,cover_photo{images}}', this.fbPermisions)
```

I used:

```
this.fb.api('/me/?fields=id%2Cname%2Calbums%7Bname%2Cpicture%2Ccover_photo%7Bimages%7D%7D', this.fbPermisions)
```

And voila, it worked .. !

Comment: what if i only need profile picture album. is there any way to get only profile picture album. Thank you